# Manage term sets in the front-end

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, managed-metadata, term-store

How to give some editor users access to certain term sets in the front-end so they can add/remove them? The route to manage this is by default: site settings > Term Store Management Tool, but we don't want to give users access to this part of the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set property of term set as "Open" which will let anyone add a new term to an open term set.

So user not necessarily need to go to the path mentioned above. In list/library while selection of term user can provide new terms as well. (same like allow fill in choices for choice field)

refer [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ee519604.aspx)